# how to use Access-Tokens for CRUD REACT JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, access-token

Given is an application for managing users. Following help files are used for this purpose:

- AuthenticationAction.js
- ManagementAction.js

AuthenticationAction.js is used for authentication:

```
export function authenticateUser(userID, password) {

  console.log("Authenticate")
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getAuthenticateUserPendingAction());
    login(userID, password).then(userSession => {
      const action = getAuthenticationSuccessAction(userSession);
      dispatch(action);
    }, error => {
      dispatch(getAuthenticationErrorAction(error));
    }).catch(error => {
      dispatch(getAuthenticationErrorAction(error));
    })
  }

}

function login(userID, password) {
  const hash = Buffer.from(`${userID}:${password}`).toString('base64')

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}`
    },

  };

  return fetch('https://localhost:443/authenticate', requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then(userSession => {
      return userSession;
    });
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  console.log(response)

  const authorizationHeader = response.headers.get('Authorization');
  return response.text().then(text => {

    if (authorizationHeader) {
      var token = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1];
    }
    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        logout();
      }
      const error = response.statusText;
      return Promise.reject(error);
    } else {
      let userSession = {
        /* user: data, */
        accessToken: token
      }
      return userSession;
    }
  });
}
```

ManagementAction.js is there for the Crud Functions.

```
export function createUser(userID, username, password) {

    console.log("Create a User")
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getShowUserManagementAction());
        createaUser(userID, username, password).then(userSession => {
            const action = getShowUserManagementActionSuccess(userSession);
            dispatch(action);
        }, error => { dispatch(getShowUserManagementErrorAction(error)); }).catch(error => { dispatch(getShowUserManagementErrorAction(error)); })
    }

}

function createaUser(userID, username, password) {
    
    const token = "whatever"
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userID: userID, userName: username, password: password })

    };
    console.log(requestOptions)
    return fetch('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(userSession => {
            return userSession;
        });
}
```

**question:**
Now if I want to use the `createaUser` function instead of the hardcoded token value with the accestoken I created in `login`, how do I get the accesstoken and how do I have to rewrite the `createaUser` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the token you created in the local storage like this:

AuthenticationAction.js

```
let userSession = {
        /* user: data, */
        accessToken: token
      }
localStorage.setItem("token", userSession.accessToken)
```

and you can access it as below:

ManagementAction.js

```
function createaUser(userID, username, password) {
    
const token = localStorage.getItem("token")    
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },


then
```

so you can send your token value with the request

Comment: Only as admin I have the right to create new users. But I have to log in as admin first and now an admin token is created. How do I set that now the token in the _createuserMethod_ ?

Comment: once you create the token where do you store it?

Comment: I don't store the token. Where should I do that ?

Comment: I edited my answer now. with setItem method, you basically save the token in your browser and you can access it with getItem method.
you can access token from inside the components/pages directly or you can also use it inside reduxstore as well. Basically it is the same thing, only difference is you decide what works best for you.

Comment: **localStorage.setItem("token", hash** in **login* and **const token** in **createauser** ?

Comment: I edited the answer one more time. the token that you create is in userSession object. So once you create the token, you save it in browser there.